# How to call any instance method in ruby object without instantiating it?

Tags: ruby, class, module, initialization, activesupport

I am creating a helper module to initialize the object before calling its methods

```
module Initialized
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def run(*args)
      new(*args).run
    end

    def call(*args)
      new(*args).call
    end

    def execute(*args)
      new(*args).create
    end
  end
end
```

So instead of defining `run`, `call`, and `execute` in my helper module I need to receive any method name and check if it exists on the main class after initializing it, then call the requested **instance** method if exists in the main class or raise an error if not

I would say my targeted code would be something like this

```
module Initialized
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  class_methods do
    def _(*args, methodname)
      new(*args).try(:send, "#{methodname}") || raise 'Method not exist'
    end
  end
end
```

Sample usage would be

```
class MyClass
  include Initialized

  def initialize(param1)
    @param1 = param1
  end

  def call
    puts "call '#{@param1}'"
  end
end
```

then calling

`MyClass.call('method param')`

I found these links but couldn't find my answer yet:

[meta-dynamic-generic-programming-in-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408230/meta-dynamic-generic-programming-in-ruby)

[ruby-module-that-delegates-methods-to-an-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712163/ruby-module-that-delegates-methods-to-an-object)

[template-methods-in-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454612/template-methods-in-ruby)

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927012/check-whether-method-named-in-a-string-is-defined-before-calling-it-with-send/61927096#61927096

Comment: @user11350468 thanks for your comment, but my challenge is how do I receive object.any_method_name() and execute it

Comment: `method_missing` is the usual way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact `method_missing` would do the job, I'd probably avoid it in this case in favor of a more explicit delegation. Simple and dirty example:

```rb
module InstanceDelegator
  def delegate_to_instance(*methods)
    methods.each do |method_name|
      define_singleton_method method_name do |*args|
        new(*args).public_send(method_name)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  extend InstanceDelegator

  delegate_to_instance :bar # <- define explicitly which instance methods
                            # should be mirrored by the class ones

  def bar
    puts "bar is called"
  end

  def baz
    puts "baz is called"
  end
end

# and then

Foo.bar #  => bar is called
Foo.baz # NoMethodError ...

# reopening works too
class Foo
  delegate_to_instance :baz
end

Foo.baz # baz is called
```

Pros:

1. you don't need to redefine `method_missing` (less magic -> less pain when you debug the code)
2. you control precisely which instance methods to be wrapped with the class level "shorthand" (fewer chances to delegate something you don't want to - more robust code)
3. (minor) no need to raise NoMethodError explicitly - you can fully rely on the core dispatching as it is...

Comment: Good solution, I like it

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution instead of using a module,
I can use the class method `self.method_missing`

```
def self.method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
  obj = new(*args)
  raise NoMethodError, "undefined method `#{method_name}' for #{self}:Class" unless obj.respond_to?(method_name)
  obj.send(method_name, &block)
end
```

But the limitation is that I have to copy it into every class whenever I need to use this feature

Comment: Thanks to [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2981429/max-pleaner) for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63672279/how-to-call-any-instance-method-in-ruby-object-without-instantiating-it/63677888#comment112600143_63672279)